# Spring boot rest serve images and other files

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest

I would like to ask if it is good approach to just serve static content like this

```
spring.web.resources.static-locations=classpath:/static/
```

so user would just go to

```
  localhost:8080/images/image.png
```

or better go with

```
@GetMapping(value = "/image/{image}")
public void userImage(HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable String image) {
    Path path = Paths.get("src\\main\\resources\\static\\UsersImages\\" + image);
    response.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE);

    try {
        InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(path);
        IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
    }catch (Exception e){
        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,"Error while streaming image!");
    }
}
```

I want to use this for users images..

In the future I would also like to serve videos etc..

Thanks

Comment: Static content is already served from that location automatically. You are basically working around the already existing feature.

Answer (score 0):

The service approach could be the best in case you wanna improve it or even extend it in the future. I suggest that the path should be a property value instead of that long string which may break the implementation in the future.

Answer (score 0):

For me, url should be without file extesions [see there](https://blog.restcase.com/7-rules-for-rest-api-uri-design/).
You can prepare few endpoints, one for images, second for videos, other for pdf files etc.

Files, I would save on other location like sftp server, DMS repository or in cloud.
If you're new, you can try put on some folder outside of project.